# The local variable a may not have been initialized | Java

Tags: java

Я делаю простенькую программу на Java, где ты должен написать в окне путь к файлу и он его прочитает, но тут появляется такая ошибка:

```
The local variable a may not have been initialized
```

Вот код:

```
int content;
String texts;


while ((content = fr.read()) != -1) {
    texts = concat((String) texts, (char) content);
}
```

Если что, у меня есть также функция `concat` которая совмещает 2 текста (String и Char). В итоге показывает что типа переменной `texts` нету в функции `concat` и получается такая ошибка.

Comment: Безотносительно к вашей ошибке, если у вас текстовый файл (содержащий символы). для его _эффективного_ чтения следует  использовать буферизованный поток ввода `BufferedReader` и считывать содержимое следует построчно, а не посимвольно или побайтово.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я только что понял свою же ошибку, ведь он не знает как можно пустую переменную прибавить к другому, поэтому я написал `String texts = "";`